# Check if a file is downloaded on click with selenium webdriver in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have to test a form on which once the user clicks submit, a file gets downloaded. I can not use the simple File.exists as on production we are using grid and the file may not be present on the same machine as the machine on which the test is run.

Answer (score 1):

On chrome I open the `chrome://downloads` page and then check downloaded files from the shadow DOM:

```
const dowloads = document
  .querySelector('downloads-manager')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloads-list')
  .getElementsByTagName('downloads-item');
```

It also contains data about file path, download-data and more, the only downside is that its limited to chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this to be honest. This link may help you. https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/

What I would do if it was a word / excel file, is to try and get selenium to ready the file from the directory the file is downloaded to. Then pass/fail the test once the read was successful.